# updateToken auth error when trying to work with application data folder

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a perfectly working drive-integrated app, javascript and go-based, with the following scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

now I try to work with Application folder. If I don't change my scopes, then I get as expected, an error claiming that app scope is not set properly. Now I add the following scope (in api-console and at my app):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata
```

now I unfortunately get an error at the oauth.updateToken googelapi function with following error message:

```
OAuthError: updateToken: 400 Bad Request
```

Have I missunderstood how Application folder is supposed to be used ?

Comment: Are you trying to exchange a new code token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show user a dialog again and retrieve a new token instead of updating the existing. Create a new auth code URL by `config.AuthCodeURL()` and ask user for permissions. Once permissions are granted by the user, exchange the code with Google endpoints by calling `t.Exchange(code)`.

```
var config = &oauth.Config{
  ClientId:     "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
  ClientSecret: "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET",
  Scope:        "YOUR_SCOPES",
  RedirectURL:  "YOUR_REDIRECT_URI",
  AuthURL:      "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  TokenURL:     "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
}

authUrl := config.AuthCodeURL("state")
fmt.Printf("Go to the following link in your browser: %v\n", authUrl)
t := &oauth.Transport{
  Config:    config,
  Transport: http.DefaultTransport,
}

// Read the code, and exchange it for a token.
fmt.Printf("Enter verification code: ")
var code string
fmt.Scanln(&code)
_, err := t.Exchange(code)
if err != nil {
  fmt.Printf("An error occurred exchanging the code: %v\n", err)
}
```

Comment: thanks, this makes perfect sense, about retrieving new token instead of updating the old. I did solve the problem (before reading this answer) by removing / reinstalling  the app from the chrome webstore AND de-authorizing on google accounts / manage apps), which I assume brought things into a clean state so there was no token to update.